# How to make a solid red dot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

This is what I typed out. My red dot is transparent. Is there any way to make it solid, to where you can't see the lines going through it?
Also please feel free to clean up my code or make any corrections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\vertex}[2]{\filldraw ({#1},{#2}) circle (0.12)}

\definecolor{mygreen1}{RGB}{0,200,0}
\definecolor{mygreen2}{RGB}{0,150,0}
\definecolor{mygreen3}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\definecolor{mygreen4}{RGB}{0,50,0}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw[very thick] (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,0);
\node at (-.25,-0.25) {\Large $A$};
\node at (3.2,-.25) {\Large $B$};
\node at (2,2.3) {\Large $C$};
\node[blue] at (0.65,1.025) {\Large $M$};
\node[blue] at (2.85,1.025) {\Large $N$};
\node[blue] at (1.5,-0.25) {\Large $P$}; 
\filldraw (1,1) circle (.05);
\filldraw (2.5,1) circle (.05);
\filldraw (1.5,0) circle (.05);
\filldraw[red] (1.67,0.67) circle (.05);
\draw[blue] (1,1) -- (3,0);
\draw[blue] (2.5,1) -- (0,0);
\draw[blue] (1.5,0) -- (2,2);

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){P}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){M}
\tkzDefPoint(2,2){C}
\tkzDefPoint(2.5,1){N}
\tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){P}

\tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,M)
\tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](M,C)
\tkzMarkSegment[mark=||](C,N)
\tkzMarkSegment[mark=||](N,B)
\tkzMarkSegment[mark=|||](A,P)
\tkzMarkSegment[mark=|||](P,B)

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: If you load `tkz-euclide` only to add marksYou use two big hammers to crush a small fly... You can do that without `tkz-euclide` or only with it . I give a solution to do what you want only with `tkz-euclide`.

Comment: I change the order of midpoints A,M  B,N  C,P I think it's more logical

Answer (score 10):

I used v 3.01 for this answer. The problem is the same with `tkz-euclide` because it uses `TikZ`'s options. It's why because it's possible with `tkz-euclide` I prefer the method : **Define, Calculus, Drawing, Marking an Labelling**

With three lines you get all the points !
Then you just need to draw ...

The order is important you need to finish with the points. If you look at the pgfmanual "Tutorial: Euclid’s Amber Version of the Elements" you can see that the points are drawn at the end.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  % fixed points
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,3/0/B,2/2/C}
  % calclations
  \tkzDefSpcTriangle[centroid](A,B,C){M,N,P} % centroid or medial
  \tkzDefTriangleCenter[centroid](A,B,C) \tkzGetPoint{G}
  % drawings
  \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
  \tkzDrawSegments[blue](A,M B,N C,P)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,N,P)
  \tkzDrawPoint[fill=red,draw=red](G)
  % marking
  \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|](C,M M,B)
  \tkzMarkSegments[mark=||](A,N N,C)
  \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|||](A,P P,B)
  % labelling
  % you can add some style with 
   \tikzset{label style/.append style ={font=\Large}}
  % label style is defined by the package you can refine it 
  % or add your own style
  \tkzLabelPoint[below left](A){$A$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[right](M){$M$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[left](N){$N$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[below](P){$P$}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

You can compile with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`

You can obtain the point of intersection here the center of gravity with several methods :

1. `\tkzDefTriangleCenter[centroid](A,B,C) \tkzGetPoint{G}` you can use `medial` instead of `centroid`
2. You can search the intersection `\tkzInterLL(A,M)(B,N) \tkzGetPoint{G}`
3. or with barycentric coordinates !
   `\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,B=1,C=1) \tkzGetPoint{G}`
   I think with TikZ it's a good solution instead of 'name pathetic.
4. The last `\tkzDefCentroid(A,B,C) \tkzGetPoint{G}`

Remark about `\tkzDefSpcTriangle[centroid](A,B,C){M,N,P}`
Now in the last version I added macros to define classic triangles and circles. Here we get the "medial" triangle (M,N,P).
I prefer `\tkzDefSpcTriangle[centroid,name=M](A,B,C){a,b,c}` and with that the midpoints are `Ma,Mb,Mc` or `\tkzDefSpcTriangle[centroid,name=M](A,B,C){_a,_b,_c}` now the midpoints are new references `M_a`, `M_b` and `M_c`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Your red circle is already solid, you just happen to draw things later which overlap it. If you move the `\filldraw[red] (...) circle` statement to the end everything looks good.

Also please note that the preferred syntax for `circle` is `circle[radius=<dim>]` instead of `circle(<dim>)`.

In addition you should use `-- cycle` at the end of closed paths so you don't get open corners.

In the answer I moved the blue lines up instead of the red dot down. I also used named coordinates a bit earlier and reused the names instead of giving the same coordinates multiple times. Furthermore I employed the `intersections` library to compute the position of the red dot.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, every node/.append style={font=\Large}]
  \draw[blue, name path=M--B] (1,1) coordinate(M) -- (3,0) coordinate(B);
  \draw[blue, name path=N--A] (2.5,1) coordinate(N) -- (0,0) coordinate(A);
  \draw[blue] (1.5,0) coordinate(P) -- (2,2) coordinate(C);
  \draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
  \node[below left] at (A) {$A$};
  \node[below right] at (B) {$B$};
  \node[above] at (C) {$C$};
  \node[above left,blue] at (M) {$M$};
  \node[above right,blue] at (N) {$N$};
  \node[below,blue] at (P) {$P$}; 
  \foreach\x in {P,M,N}
    \filldraw (\x) circle[radius=.05];
  \path[name intersections={of=M--B and N--A,by=Z}];
  \filldraw[red] (Z) circle[radius=.05];

  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,M)
  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](M,C)
  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=||](C,N)
  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=||](N,B)
  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|||](A,P)
  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|||](P,B)
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[@Schrödinger'scat suggested a shorter version in the comment.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526376/how-to-make-a-solid-red-dot/526377#comment1331308_526377) As I personally think that the longer version is easier to understand for newcomers I add that shorter version as a second code block.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, every label/.style={font=\Large, execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$}, every circle/.style={radius=.05}]
  \draw[blue, name path=M--B] (1,1) coordinate[label=above left:M](M) -- (3,0) coordinate[label={[black]below right:B}](B);
  \draw[blue, name path=N--A] (2.5,1) coordinate[label=above right:N](N) -- (0,0) coordinate[label={[black]below left:A}](A)
    (1.5,0) coordinate[label=below:P](P) -- (2,2) coordinate[label={[black]above:C}](C);
  \draw[very thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
  \path[name intersections={of=M--B and N--A,by=Z}];
  \foreach\x/\y in {/P,/M,/N,red/Z} \filldraw[\x] (\y) circle;

  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,M)
  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](M,C)
  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=||](C,N)
  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=||](N,B)
  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|||](A,P)
  \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|||](P,B)
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please consider using `\node[below left,font=\Large] at (A) {$A$};`, or, even better, `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,every label/.append style={font=\Large}]
  \draw[blue, name path=M--B] (1,1) coordinate[label=above left:$M$](M) -- (3,0)
  coordinate[label={[black]below right:$B$}](B);`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat `name path' is useful but in some cases it's very slow.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'd rather use tkz-euclide for intersections than marks or right angles.

Comment: You can use `\tkzMarkSegments` with (s) and here I think the use of barycentric coordinate is more efficient

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I know that this code could be further shortened, but I think shortening too much won't be good for newcomers. The `\Large` inside of nodes should be removed though, I agree.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is plain TikZ. No more package or library is needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
% pic for marking segments, use with pic options (rotate, thick, red, ...)
% markx    > x
% markl    > |
% markll   > ||
% marklll  > |||
\tikzset{
markx/.pic={\draw (45:.1)--(-135:.1) (-45:.1)--(135:.1);},
markl/.pic={\draw (90:.1)--(-90:.1);},
markll/.pic={\draw[shift={(180:.02)}] (90:.1)--(-90:.1);
             \draw[shift={(0:.02)}] (90:.1)--(-90:.1);},
marklll/.pic={\draw[shift={(180:.03)}] (90:.1)--(-90:.1);
              \draw (90:.1)--(-90:.1);
              \draw[shift={(0:.03)}] (90:.1)--(-90:.1);}         
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
(-1,0)   coordinate (A) node[below left]{$A$}
(4,0)    coordinate (B) node[below right]{$B$}
(0,3.5)  coordinate (C) node[above]{$C$}
(A)--(B) coordinate[pos=.5] (M) (M) node[below]{$M$}
(B)--(C) coordinate[pos=.5] (N) (N) node[above right]{$N$}
(C)--(A) coordinate[pos=.5] (P) (P) node[above left]{$P$};

\draw[gray] (A)--(N) (B)--(P) (C)--(M);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;

% markings
\path 
(A)--(B) pic[pos=.25,red]{markx} pic[pos=.75,red]{markx}
(B)--(C) pic[pos=.25,rotate=-30]{markll} pic[pos=.75,rotate=-30]{markll}
(C)--(A) pic[pos=.25,blue,thick,rotate=45]{markl} pic[pos=.75,blue,thick,rotate=45]{markl};

% G is the centroid of triangle ABC
\path (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) coordinate (G);

% fill points with solid dots
\fill[magenta] (G) circle(1.5pt) +(-110:.3) node{$G$};
\foreach \p in {A,B,C,M,N,P} 
\fill (\p) circle(1.5pt);
%\draw[fill=white] (\p) circle(1.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just(only) for fun.

```
import psteuclasy;// https://github.com/justonly011298/psteuclasy
size(300);
defaultpen(linewidth(0.3mm));

pair A=(0,0),B=(3,0),C=(2,2);
pair M=pstMiddleAB(B,C),N=pstMiddleAB(A,C),P=pstMiddleAB(B,A);
draw(A--B--C--cycle);
pstSegmentMark(B--M^^M--C,invisible,MarkHash(angle=0));
pstSegmentMark(A--N^^N--C,invisible,MarkHashh(angle=0));
pstSegmentMark(A--P^^P--B,invisible,MarkHashhh(angle=0));
draw(A--M^^B--N^^C--P,blue);
dot("A",A,SW); 
dot("B",B,SE); 
dot("C",(2,2),-S); // N = Relative((0,1)) = -S
dot("M",M,E); 
dot("N",N,W); 
dot("P",P,S);
dot(pstCGravABC(A,B,C),red);
```

[image]